# Get ExecutionContext.InvocationId in startup (Azure function V2)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, azure-functions

Currently I can retrieve ExecutionContext inside the function method, like this:

```
public async Task <IActionResult> Run ([HttpTrigger (AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)], ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
```

Is there any way I can retrieve ExecutionContext from my function startup?

Comment: `ExecutionContext` has multiple parameters, and I suggest to clarify the question on what exactly you need at startup. Otherwise the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry that you will not be able to get the [ExecutionContext](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/v2.x/src/WebJobs.Extensions/Extensions/Core/ExecutionContext.cs) in startup.  Because the ExecutionContext enables interaction with the Azure Functions execution environment when a function call is made.

However, in your function startup, your Azure Function is not yet processing an actual function call.